# how to? i want to use 2 NSMutableData

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledata

i want to use 2 NSMutableData
from viewDidLoad 
how to use it?

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) id sMemberID;
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSMutableData *receivedData2;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSString *statusMem;
```

Comment: This is iOS code, how it is related with `PHP`?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: this is in objective-c...and can be for ios as well as osx. :)

Comment: @user2003023.... you have created two objects of nsdata, now what is your problem?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yeah I knows that, I am asking to OP why he has tagged with `PHP`.

Comment: @user2003023 : @ Anoop Vaidya  is correct what is your real problem ?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: he might be using some `obj-c + php` project. as per his reupation and question quality, i guess is a new learner.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya May be... ;)

Comment: if i want data from json(php) add to ReceivedData1 ok

Comment: but i not add json2(php) add to ReceivedData2 in viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

lets say that you have receiveData and receiveData2 are in ViewController called NextViewController,

then we can do like this,

```
NextViewController *nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
[nextViewController setReceivedData: sendData1];
[nextViewController setReceivedData2: sendData2];
[self presentViewController:NextViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

also change nonatomic,assign to nonatomic strong

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableData *receivedData2;
```